# Multichannel sequence analysis through WeightedCluster package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, sequences, traminer

I would like to apply the functions available in the `WeightedCluster` package to analyze multichannel sequences I obtained through `TraMineR`. I am trying so, but due to the fact that multichannel sequences are lists composed by each channel separatedly, I get errors in functions like `seqtreedisplay()` and all those which require a `sequence object`.

This is an example:

```
fullsequences <- list(
  work_sequence2 = work_sequence[which(rownames(work_sequence) %in% commonid),],
  educ_sequence2 = educ_sequence[which(rownames(educ_sequence) %in% commonid),],
  part_sequence2 = part_sequence[which(rownames(part_sequence) %in% commonid),],
  kid_sequence2 = kid_sequence[which(rownames(kid_sequence) %in% commonid),]
)  # a total of 926 with complete sequences on all channels

multidist <- seqdistmc(
          channels = fullsequences,
          method = "OM", 
          norm = FALSE, 
          sm = list("TRATE","TRATE","TRATE","TRATE"), 
          with.missing=FALSE, 
          full.matrix=TRUE, 
          link="sum")  

clusterward <- hclust(as.dist(multidist), method = "ward")  

seqtreedisplay(as.seqtree(clusterward, ncluster = 5,
           seqdata = fullsequences , diss = multidist))

Error in seqlegend(seqdata, fontsize = legend.fontsize, title = "Legend",  : 
  data is not a sequence object, use seqdef function to create one
```

Is there a method to use the functionalities of `WeightedCluster` package upon a multichannel-type object (list of sequences). I am specially interested in using the *Partition Around Medioids* algorithm with initial ward clusters (function `wcKMedioids()`). If it is not possible, which is the best alternative to cluster multichannels in `R`?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `as.seqtree` function (from `WeightedCluster`) requires an object of class `stslist` (as produced by the `TraMineR` `seqdef` function) as `seqdata` argument. In your case, `fullsequences` is a list of such objects (the list of parallel sequences), which is NOT itself of class `stslist`. This causes the error.

Even if you would be able to define a tree of parallel sequences, the problem would be that the `seqtreedisplay` does not know how to plot parallel sequences. This means that you would have to define a plot function for a list of state sequences and, using the more general `disstreedisplay` function instead of `seqtreedisplay`, pass the plot function as `imagefunc` argument.

To summarize, there are two problems. First you need some `as.disstree` equivalent of `as.seqtree` that would work for hierarchical clustering of non-stslist objects. Second, you need a plot function for parallel sequences. The first problem is purely technical and should be easily solved. The second is more conceptual.